# Storing statistics over longer periods of time and timezones

Tags: mysql, database, date, database-design, timezone

Currently I'm working on a project which calculates data and stores it by ID in a analytics database.

For example the amount of times a news article is read (and so there are like 20 categories of data stored as integer).

We store the data in fields as followed:
int user_id
int value_type_id
int value
datetime datetime

We use 4 tables, x_hour, x_day, x_week, x_month
This way we won't have to calculate the data over a potential few thousands or even millions of records.

The data needs to be calculated on the fly and filtered by certain joins.
This is all no problem and works as intended and at a speed which is satisfactory.

The issue that follows. We want the data to display in the timezone of the user who views it, the timezone is not always the same since it can be antying, for example UTC-5 or UTC+4.

Since we store the dates on UTC we are having problems with intervals on days,weeks and months since if activity is stored an hour before midnight the larger intervals will see it as yesterday, even though it could be on the same day in that timezone.

I've read solutions as adding 24 columns to hold the data for every timezone, does anyone have a different solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. Are you saying that you want to report on events based on the time they occur locally?

Comment: Nope, I store them by day hour week and month, thus we need 40 columns for the timezones, since all data for week 20 can be different in timezone +12 as in +0.

But it has been done. ages ago ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the only way to go is using buckets of 15 minutes, or exactly defined timezones, cause that would get only about 40 columns.

Then we have todo the same for days weeks and months so we have correct data for each timezone.

A bit more time consuming and taking more data storage, but if we keep our data clean it might be a decent enough solution.

Comment: You have not found any other solution since ?

Comment: There is no other decent solution, the best thing would be to get your mysql and stuff running on SSD to make everything fast ;). But no other code sollutions.

Comment: Thx, Can you show a design example for this table you talked about (15min bucket + timezones) ?

Comment: I did not go for a 15 minute bucket table, since I'm using codeigniter we're using a table like:
datetime, value, value_type_id, UM12, UM11 till UTC till UP14

You'd probably be better of using normal timezones or make an entire custom design, I mean our data from 4 july clock in UTC-12 (UM12) is the same as 3 july UTC+12 (UP12) so we do have some double data stored.

But I guess you get the idea, we have 40 columns for all the timezones now with a datetimestamp to indicate the time at that timezone.

Comment: How do you deal with time zones that switch offsets for daylight saving time?  Sometimes you will look in one column, and sometimes in another, but what to do on the day of the transition?  Prorate a bit to each?  Or do you not need that level of precision?

Comment: Well pretty simple, since it is all stored ignoring DST (so never the hour increase) we can display it for that specific user. Currently in the application we do not take this into account we just display it either with or without the extra hour depending on the user's settings.

Comment: Not trying to stir up the pot, but most users in the modern world *are* affected by DST.  Ignoring it means you are giving them data that doesn't align to their expectations.  Sometimes that is ok, but you seemed to specifically be after a *precise* solution.  If you haven't already, please read the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) - especially "Time Zone != Offset".

Comment: That data is still available, are you still looking for a sollution? cause going further down this discussion is not helping anyone.

Comment: Ok, I was just trying to help.  I see the open bounty, so I thought you or lighta were still looking for assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Continue to store the datetimes in UTC.

Pass in the user's timezone to the query.

Convert in the `SELECT`, using the [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`datetimefield`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam')
```

Where 'Europe/Amsterdam' is replaced with the appropriate timezone.

You're better off using IANA timezone strings as above, instead of offsets like 'UTC-5', as long as you have this data available. It will correctly handle issues surrounding daylight savings in the regions where this takes place.

Further notes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html
- This program is used to intialise MySQL with timezone data.

Comment: Not exactly what I need read below (out of chars)

What I need to know is if there is a proper way for storing the data over larger intervals.

For example a daily storage will contain a date like:
2013-03-29 00:00:00, this will be UTC. But it will have wrong data for someone in a timezone different than UTC.

Example, I'm in GMT+1 if I post something on 00:30 local time, the system will generate data telling the viewer I posted that the day before. Since it's stored by day.

The problem is that if I keep using hours the system will get way too slow for data over periods of a month or longer.

Comment: I see, I'd suggest adding `to` and `from` datetime columns that represent the start and end of each hourly interval, and thus storing 24 UTC based rows for each day and such of data. The select would then be able to retrieve the correct converted set of 24 rows for the given user-time day.

Comment: @bcmcfc - That solution only works if all of your target timezones have full hour offsets.  Several have 30 minute offsets and there are even a couple that are 45 minute offset.  So if you want the whole world, you need 15-minute increment buckets.